# how to make 30 seconds timer

Tags: motor, timer

I'm trying to make a timer, that powers the small motor for 1-2 seconds, every 30 seconds.
I need this to be portable. Can someone help me?

the motor I have is using 3 V voltage, also I don't want to use any microcontrollers.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45104/diy-small-motor-that-turns-for-x-seconds-every-y-seconds